# If condicions inside email body

Tags: javascript, android

I'm building an app that will send an email with variables, but i only want to include certain things **if** a variable is true (checkbox)

So I think i need If statments inside the `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");` but I dont seem to figure out how. it would look something like this:

```
public  void  Email (){
       Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY  HH.mm");
       String Time = formatter.format(today);

       Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
       email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Audit" );
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Time + "\n" + "Audit Results:"
               if (MainActivity2.Send_A)=true{
                   MainActivity2.Ok_A1 + "\n" + MainActivity2.EditText1 + "\n" + MainActivity2.POA1

       }
       );

I know the code is completly wrong, but is it possible to do something like this?
```

Comment: I'm probably better off doing everyting on a single string or array, but the question remains

Comment: `if (MainActivity2.Send_A)=true{` well that is a syntax error plus you can't have an if randomly in the middle like that.

Comment: Build a string, set it when you are done. `var str = "ASDF"; if (foo===bar) { str += "QWERTY" }; console.log(str);`

Answer (score 0):

Build up the string, than set that string to your function call.

```
var extraText = Time + "\n" + "Audit Results: ";
if (MainActivity2.Send_A === true){
  extraText += MainActivity2.Ok_A1 + "\n" + MainActivity2.EditText1 + "\n" + MainActivity2.POA1;
}

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText);
```